# Change keyboard default language flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField and it opens keyboard in phone default language. I need to open keyboard only in English language. Is it possible to do it in flutter?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The only power you have over the keyboard in flutter textfield is whether to show number, date time or default text keyboard.

```
    TextField( 
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
)
```

You can follow this [medium article about textfields](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-flutter-textfields-f0e676aaab7a) in flutter for more information.
You can use a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard_multi_language/score) maybe but I wouldn't recommend it since it doesn't support null safety, but according to its documentation its a virtual keyboard which supports multiple languages